# Docx to pdf convertion in PHP adding new lines automatically - PHPWord

Tags: php, tcpdf, phpword, phpoffice

I am converting docx file to pdf using PHP library PHPOffice and PHPWord. I am using TCPDF as PDF writer.

My code is as below

```
include_once 'Sample_Header.php';
include_once '../vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath('../vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('TCPDF');

$temp = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('files/sampledocument.docx');
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($temp , 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save('results/sampledocument.pdf', TRUE);
```

Its working fine and generating correct pdf file only if docx file is containing plain text without any style changes(i.e color, text-bold). But if docx file containing stylings then in pdf its starting from new line.

For example docx file contains

```
Hello World
```

This is showing correct in pdf file. But if docx file contains as below ("H" and "W" is bold here)

```
**H**ello **W**orld
```

Its showing in pdf as below (Instead of showing in one line its showing in multiple lines)

```
H
ello
W
orld
```

Please let me know you any one is having solution for this. Thanks in advance.